# How to skip 2nd and 4th Saturday between 2 dates using java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have requirement as follows I have two dates i need to skip 2nd and 4th saturdays and sundays between the dates.
for example  Date1: 01/12/2017
             Date2: 11/12/2017 
output :8 days are weekends

Thanks Chakri

Comment: Consider that you're reading this question and know nothing else about what's involved, would *you* understand the context? Do you think this would be enough for you to compose an answer? Please, take a read of the "[ask]" and "[mcve]" guidelines, then [edit] your question to include sufficient information that we're able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var totalSaturday = 0;
    var totalSundays = 0;
    for (var i = fromDate; i <= toDate;) {

        if (i.getDay() == 0) {
            totalSundays++;
        }

        if (i.getDay() == 6) {

                var day=i.getDate() / 7;
                var week = Math.floor(day);
                if(day.toString().indexOf('.')==1)
                {
                    if(week =="1" || week == "3"){
                        totalSaturday++;                        
                    } 
                }
                else
                {   if(week =="2" || week == "4"){
                    totalSaturday++;                        
                }
                }
            }

        i.setTime(i.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var lock = false;    
    if(('currentdate' = 'saturday') || ('currentdate' = 'sunday')){
if(lock=false){
    //do some code here
    lock=true;
    } else {
    //do some code here whatever you gonna do at 2nd and 4th weekend
    lock = false;
    }
}
```

This will let you to do your base code on 1st and 3rh weekends and then you will lock it for next time. 2nd and 4th will be doing the else code what ever it is.

Comment: As I understand he is trying to go 1 filled and one blanked with js. He will get the day by using JS and will be matching it with a day array to get currentdate variable (I just didnt bother with that code as well). if currentdate is saturday or sunday it will be checking if lock is true or false. if true that means its the first saturday or sunday. so do the code. else that means it is the second which he wants to jump on it and continue with return.

Comment: we cant give a predictive answer to someone who wants a solution, let him post some of his code, then answer . More so now your code looks like a pseudo one. and cant compare like this `'currentdate' = 'saturday'`